# Radio Streaming AVPlayer latency (delay) is to high swift 3

Tags: swift, avplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

In my app I play audio live streaming and the delay is very important. I'm using AVPlayer but it takes 5-6 sec to start and I need it 3 sec max of delay. How can I do it to start playing faster and reduce that delay?
Set a small buffer will do the job? how to set it up with AVPlayer?

This is my RadioPlayer class:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class RadioPlayer {
    static let sharedInstance = RadioPlayer()
    private var player = AVPlayer()

    private var isPlaying = false
    private var language: LanguageDOM?

    func play() {
        player.play()
        isPlaying = true
    }

    func pause() {
        player.pause()
        isPlaying = false
    }

    func toggle() {
        if isPlaying == true {
            pause()
        } else {
            play()
        }
    }

    func currentTimePlaying() -> CMTime {
        return player.currentTime()
    }

    func changeLanguage(nlanguage: LanguageDOM){
        self.pause()
        self.language = nlanguage
        player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(string: nlanguage.url)! as URL)
        self.play()
    }

    func currentlyPlaying() -> Bool {
        return isPlaying
    }

    func currentLanguage() -> LanguageDOM {
        return self.language!
    }

    func currentLanguageId() -> Int {
        if self.language == nil {
            return -1
        }
        else {
            return language!.id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought implementing AVAudioSession but I can't understand it

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your network is fast enough to load the necessary buffer for 3 second delays.

What you want to look at is the `-prerollAtRate:` of `AVPlayer`. When used properly, it will allow for minimal latency between when you press play, and when you hear the sound. It requires however that part of the song be downloaded already for processing.

As for AVAudioSession, it is not what you're looking for, AVPlayer is the correct class for you.

If AVPlayer isn't fast enough I suggest looking into [BASS](http://un4seen.com) which is a low level C like audio library built upon AudioUnits framework which allow for precise and fast control over your stream.